# Adding labels to the trees in angular-ui-tree

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

Is there a way to add labels or separate trees to the angular-ui-tree?

I have a JSON file with questions that I'm feeding the `$scope.tree` to display in my front end.  I would like to have a separate tree to get the answers to those questions.

Is this possible?

I have included a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate model for both:

For the question, use:

```
<label for="categoryName">{{node.nodes.length}} {{$index + 1 + "-"}} {{node.title}}</label>
```

And for the answer, use:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer" id="categoryName" ng-model="node.answer">
```